# React Native: How to implement carousel of images with zoom in FlatList component?

Tags: image, react-native, carousel, react-native-flatlist

I use a `FlatList` component for images grid because it have a good performance:

```
<FlatList
  data={photos}

  columnWrapperStyle={styles.listColumn}
  numColumns={4}

  renderItem={photo => this.renderPhoto(photo)}
/>
```

For now `renderPhoto` func return a new [FastImage](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) component (*i use it because it have a cool caching feature*)

```
<FastImage
  resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
  source={{uri: photo.src}}
/>
```

In the end I have something like this:

[image: Grid of images]

But now I want to have a very familiar possibility. Tap on the image will start the animation after which the image will be stretched to the full width of the screen.

After that, the user can do the following:

- Swipe left/right to see prev/next images from the `FlatList`
- Zoom current image
- Tap on image to show/hide control elements (footer and header)
- Swipe up/down for closing carousel and return to the grid component

It might look something like this:

[image: Carousel and lightbox]

So, whats a problem?

All existing carousel solutions are a wrapper for an image collection. But I cant pass wrapper component inside `FlatList`.

I could not find a ready-made component for solving such a common problem.
There are some that I try to combine ([Lightbox](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox), [Carousel](https://github.com/nick/react-native-carousel)). But this solution will greatly affect performance. *(I need to load the entire collection of images from the `FlatList` into the carousel component)* In addition, such solutions usually have problems with animation.

**So I'm wondering if there really is no `react-native` solution for such a popular image view mechanics?**

Perhaps it is worth making a native module on the `swift`/`objc` (FlatList of images with carousel modal)?

Comment: Hello @Yury, did you find a solution for your question? I have exactly the same question. I don't find any good solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Actually is possible with the elements that you have.

First you have the carousel (react-native-looped-carousel):

```
const activeProps = {
  resizeMode: 'contain',
  flex: 1,
  width: null
};

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const renderCarousel = (album, currentPage) => (
  <Carousel style={{ width, height }} currentPage={currentPage} autoplay={false}>
    {album.map(image => (
      <FastImage
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
        source={{ uri: image.uri }}
        key={image.uri}
      />))
    }
  </Carousel>
);
```

Then FastImage (react-native-fast-image) with the lightbox (react-native-lightbox):

```
  LightImage = (props) => {
    const currentPage = this.items.findIndex(x => x.uri === props.source.uri);
    return (
      <Lightbox
        activeProps={activeProps}
        renderContent={() => renderCarousel(this.items, currentPage)}
      >
        <FastImage {...props} />
      </Lightbox>
    );
  }
```

Now you can use your renderItem with the component for the FastImage and Lightbox

```
<FlatList
  data={this.items}

  columnWrapperStyle={styles.listColumn}
  numColumns={4}

  renderItem={photo => this.LightImage(photo)}
/>
```

I've copied part of my code, so it won't work with just copy and paste. If you have any question feel free to ask!
There's only one problem with this implementation that if you rotate the device the layout breaks

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How about performance of your solution? For example, if there are more than 1000 photos in the collection.

Comment: You have two things, first of all you shouldn't have a list of 1000 items to render at the same time, you need to use pagination and retrieve x results and use onEndReached with onEndReachedThreshold of Flatlist to retrieve the next results to render.
In the other side, Flatlist just render what you have in screen.
It's actually REALLY fast in terms of rendering with Fastimage when the image is already cached

Comment: For some reason this solution works on android, but on iOS it jsut displays a black screen when the image is tapped.